# Need some help - left shift bitwise operator

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, operators

I am trying to clearly understand the behaviour of the shift operators (especially for the boundary cases), so I devised a little test written in C++.

```
    int a = odd_value; //321 in my case but it should not matter (the last bit to be 1)
    print(0, a);

    a = a << 31; // (this gives a segmentation fault, as normal because it tries the sign bit becomes 1 but all the other bits are 0).
    print(0, a); //the segmentation fault happens here - it prints the minimum integer value and then gives the fault
    a = (a << 1) + 1; // but if then I do this, shouldn't it set a to -1 ??
    print(a); //gives 0

   void print(int stackCallIndex, int nb)
   {
     if(nb)
     {
        print(++stackCallIndex, nb >> 1);
        if(nb & 1) printf("%d", 1);
        else       printf("%d", 0);

        if(stackCallIndex % 8 == 0) printf(" ");
     }
   }
```

Comment: This is what I get if I try to print a just after the bitshift. Let me edit the post so it's a bit clearer.

Comment: You should never get a segmentation fault from printing an `int` O.o

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @SlowTrout What is the actual value of `a`, and how are you defining `print`?

Comment: The shift operator wouldn't generate the segmentation fault. If print expects a char* (string), or maybe an integer that you try printing as a string, then naturally blammo.

Comment: My bad. The segmentation fault is happening when trying to print the binary form of the integer. I will add the print function just now.

Comment: @SlowTrout wait, do you even get any output? To me it looks like infinite recursion for negative numbers...

Comment: Raphael Miedl, you are just right. I have just put a print inside the function and indeed it is an infinite recursion - i've missed this.  Though by adding a new bit at the end should it show -1? 1(30 x 0)1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code I'd bet on a stackoverflow due to infinite recursion if you try to print negative values.

```
   void print(int stackCallIndex, int nb)
   {
     if(number)
     {
        print(++stackCallIndex, nb >> 1); // likely an infinite recursion here.
        if(nb & 1) printf("%d", 1);
        else       printf("%d", 0);

        if(stackCallIndex % 8 == 0) printf(" ");
     }
   }
```

so why would it be infinite recursion? Strictly according to standard right shifting negative signed integers is implementation defined.

In most implementations it will do an [arithmetic right shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift), meaning that `1111 1100` (-4 in two's complement 8bit) shifted to the right by 1 would result in `1111 1110` (-2 in two's complement 8bit) as you can see you always fill up the sign bit again so your number would never get to 0 and the if condition is always true.

---

Generally doing bit manipulation on signed values is a bad idea, they involve implementation/undefined behavior in a few cases. Better cast all values to unsigned before using bit manipulation.

Comment: So it will never go to 0 because the sign bit is always preserved?

Comment: @SlowTrout Yes. Try changing the parameter from `int nb` to `unsigned nb` and it should work.

Comment: It does. Thanks a lot. Can you please point me towards a sound piece of documentation regarding these operators?

Comment: Sadly [the standard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/1942027) would probably be the best here (although hard due to the legalise writing style). You can find the shift operators by searching `expr.shift`. I usually use [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) as a easier reference but I don't find it's pages about the built in operators all that good...

Answer (score 3):

If you want the *standard* behavior, then it's undefined. According to [expr.shift]:

> The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If `E1` has an unsigned
>   type, [...]. Otherwise, if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and `E1`×`2`<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the
>   resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Any (odd number > 1) x 2<sup>31</sup> is not representable by `uint32_t`, so the behavior is undefined. Your compiler apparently chooses to implement this as a segmentation fault, which is perfectly conforming behavior (edit: er, at least it would be, if that were where it is happening).

A more typical approach would be just to let bits "fall off" the end. That is, `a << 31` for an odd number would become `0x80000000`. But even in that case, another left-shift of 1 would result in `0`, so you'd have to subtract 1 to get `-1`, not add `1`.

Comment: Strictly according to standard, yes. Doubt any compiler actually does that though and I'd guess for infinite recursion with OP's no added code.

Comment: This makes sense.Can you please point me out towards the documentation you have just posted. There are tones of posts across the web, but no one fully explains the boundary cases.

Comment: @SlowTrout The reference is from the C++ standard, in this case specifically revision N4140.

Answer (score 1):

When I try that I get -214783648 which is the smallest known value in integer... this means that you are making an integer bigger than the allowed range that's why in your case you get a segmentation fault...

Comment: The problem is in the print function - apparently it goes into infinite looping.

Comment: let me check it an I will let you know

Comment: your function has an error... number must be nb... in addition it needs two arguments how do you pass just one argument to it?

Comment: that's a typo - it wouldn't compile otherwise

Comment: your problem is nb>>1

Comment: I figured that, I need to know why, but I think Raphael just pointed it out.